# How to pass login credentials to asp server from android app

Tags: java, android

From researching I have found out, that I can send information to a server using HttpPost so I have.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp");
```

I have two EditText fields to hold the userId and password, and a button for login.

```
EditText id ;
EditText pword ;
Button logIn ;

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", id.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pword.getText().toString()));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));//already inside a try/catch() block

new getResponse().execute()     

 // in AsyncTask
 public abstract class getResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

     public String doInBackground(){
         try {
             HttpResonse response = client.execute(post);
         String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     Log.d("response to string", responseContent);
         }/...
```

Now in the LogCat I see the html of this "https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp", however, when checking the entity with
    System.out.println(post.getEntity());
i get "org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity@41237c10" however I am not getting the page in response that I am supposed to, which is the page after login, instead i get the HTML of "post". What am I doing wrong.

Note: compiling in 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the content to consume the message:

```
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
```

then you can read your InputStream